# ASP.Net MVC How to pass url parameters using Html.RenderAction to a ChildAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I thought this was going to be straight forward but I managed to hose it up some how. If I want to pass URL parameters to another action do I have to create a new route for that?

controller

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult ContentSection(string sectionAlias, string mvcController, string mvcAction = null)
```

view

```
@Html.RenderAction("ContentSection", "Portal", new {sectionAlias = "TermsAndConditions", mvcController = "Portal", mvcAction = "ChoosePayment"})
```

error

```
 CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
@Html.RenderAction("ContentSection", "Portal", new {sectionAlias = "TermsAndConditions", mvcController = "Portal", mvcAction = "ChoosePayment"})
```

Is the equivalent to

```
<%= Html.RenderAction("ContentSection", "Portal", new {sectionAlias = "TermsAndConditions", mvcController = "Portal", mvcAction = "ChoosePayment"}) %>
```

In the the Webforms `ViewEngine` (which is also the same a `Response.Write`).  Since `RenderAction` returns `void`, you cannot `Response.Write` it.  What you want to do is this:

```
@{
     Html.RenderAction("ContentSection", "Portal", new {sectionAlias = "TermsAndConditions", mvcController = "Portal", mvcAction = "ChoosePayment"});
 }
```

The `@{ }` syntax signifies a code block in the Razor view engine, which would be equivalent to the following the the Webforms `ViewEngine`:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("ContentSection", "Portal", new {sectionAlias = "TermsAndConditions", mvcController = "Portal", mvcAction = "ChoosePayment"}); %>
```

Comment: Or you can call @Html.Action(...) instead, in order to call it as a method that returns your content (if you don't like using the curly brackets, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out by reading another similar post. Thanks! I think this got me once before too..

Comment: Yes, this is really a well-written answer. Thanks Nathan! And thanks to James Nail, too. Your hint was also valuable.

Answer (score 16):

The short answer is to use `@Html.Action()` like this:

```
@Html.Action("ContentSection", "Portal", new {sectionAlias = "Terms", ...})
```

The [long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964042/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-url-parameters-using-html-renderaction-to-a-childaction/4964376#4964376) was already given by Nathan Anderson.

P.S. Credit for this answer really goes to James Nail, who posted it as a comment in Nathan's answer, but I found it so easy and valuable that I thought it should be an individual answer.