# Asp.net MVC 3 error when calling Html.RenderAction

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a newbie to asp.net mvc 3. How can you render a view within a div by calling an action:

html:

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
 @Html.RenderAction("Popup","Home");
</div>
```

c#:

```
public  ActionResult Popup()
    {
       return PartialView();
    }
```

I am getting an error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964042/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-url-parameters-using-html-renderaction-to-a-childaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your HtmlHelper in a code block:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Popup", "Home"); }
```

Comment: I prefer doing `@Html.Action();` instead of this, as documentation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980823/html-renderpartial-syntax-with-razor/6980974#6980974

Answer (score -2):

From Wrox.Professional.ASP.NET.MVC.3.Aug.2011 page 115

> Html.Action and Html.RenderAction Action and RenderAction are similar
>   to the Partial and RenderPartial helpers. The Partial helper typically
>   helps a view render a portion of a view’s model using view markup in a
>   separate file.  Action, on the other hand, executes a separate
>   controller action and displays the results. Action offers more
>   flexibility and re-use, because the controller action can build a
>   different model and make  use of a separate controller context.  Once
>   again, the only difference between Action and RenderAction is that
>   RenderAction writes  directly to the response (which can bring a
>   slight efficiency gain).